# Apache - set application MIME type based on URL or directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have some images in my content whose url look like

http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/cdn/2014/10/08/w3V7WGRjaj5FUXx6wM5LIA4eyfmmB0grX0cIvPw2qf-O1mhQ2qwYPEHddAeVer62LLkZFrEV7fSQCxSR-J_CjPxncwLfbmjkdKNE_Gt1eENqMD5ikc9Bwl-NhSdePmjn2g

These are image files, with no extension.

They render as images on my webhost.

I moved to a different server, and currently when the same url is opened, the browser offers the image as text file for download.

I believe the application/mime type is not being set to image by the new apache server.

i tried adding a htaccess snippet as

```
<Directory "sites/default/cdn/*">
 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    AddType image/png .png
</Directory>
```

And also tried several other combinations like giving a specific directory instead of a *, etc. But no luck so far.

Any pointers?

Comment: `AddType image/png .png` would add that content-type to all files that have the suffix `.png`. So that’s rather pointless, when your image files have been stored _without_ a suffix.

Comment: Look into [`ForceType`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype)  instead.